# How to have separate javadoc jar file for java code from src/main and for java code from src/test?

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

My project tree is as follows :

```
src/
main
└── java
    └── com
        └── development
                └── feature
                    └── Library.java
└── test 
    └── java
        └── com 
            └── development
                └── feature
                    └── Sample.java
```

I delivered Library.java in a jar file (with mvn deploy command) and Sample.java in a zip file (using maven assembly).
As my goal is to deliver a jar library file and provide a Sample.java as an example about the way to use the jar library.
I managed to generate a javadoc for my Library.java file updating my pom.xml as follows (and thanx to mvn deploy command):

```
...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
...
```

But I would like also to generate a separate javadoc file for the Sample.java which is in test folder.

I saw that I could generate a javadoc containing both Library.java code and Sample.java through eclipse
with File/Export/selecting @Javadoc in fact using javadoc.exe from Amazon Coretto jdk11.
But this is not what I want.
I want a javadoc jar file for the code from src/main and a javadoc jar file for the code from src/tst when I execute mvn deploy command.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanx

Comment: did you try to add goal test-javadoc as in https://github.com/eliasgranderubio/pfm-mustic9/blob/8edeb2a807d2b95d75792fc98b943a7bfce93507/master/master_db_ws/pom.xml#L32, looks like it will create javadoc for test.

Comment: Hi thanx for your reply but It seems that the goal test-javadoc still generates the javadoc of the main source (as I already have but it is not in a jar file as I did but in a site folder) if I replace the  verify phase in your example by package (and do a mvn package). But still no javadoc for the test part of my project. But I will further look at your clue as it should work if I look at this link as well => https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/test-javadoc-mojo.html